# Finding probability that two discrete random variables are equal

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I am trying to find $P[X=Y]$  for two random, independent variables, having probability distribution functions:
$f(x) = (1/10)(9/10)^x$ for $X = 0, 1, 2,...    $
$f(y) = (1/5)(4/5)^y$ for $Y = 0, 1, 2,...$

Since X and Y are independent, their joint density function is $f(x) \times f(y)$.
Is it correct to sum over the product of the individual functions of X and Y, setting $x=y$?

Comment: Yes, your direction is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The main idea is notice that:$\Pr[X=Y]=\Pr[\bigcup_{i} (X=i \land Y=i)] =\sum_{i} \Pr[X=i \land Y=i]$ and use the definition of independence.

Comment: You probably mean $Pr[\cup_i(X=i \cap Y=i)]$

Comment: Yup, thanks Alex.